# Lightbox position won't stay put inside fixed position div

Tags: css, iframe, modal-dialog, position, lightbox

I loosely followed a basic CSS lightbox template from w3 schools for modal lightboxes.  I haven't gotten to the Javascript yet, but just laying out the look and style of the lightbox.

I have a fixed position div element serving as the grey background, and inside that the "lightbox-content" div to hold an iframe of a Vimeo link.  I followed a workaround to make the iframe responsive by containing it inside another div and adjusting the styling.  I want the max-width of my iframe to be 1280px, but up to 100% width on anything smaller.

Everything works great on smaller screens, the iframe and contained link fills the width, stays vertically centered, and scales with the page.  However, when I go above the 1280, the iframe moves in all sorts of weird ways.  I'd like to have it so when the page width goes about 1280 or so,the iframe just stays at a fixed size in the center of the screen at 1280px wide.

I tried using an @media query to change some of the CSS rules, but I'm getting so lost in the position after several hours of trying.  I think what's throwing me is having so many div with different types of positioning inside each other, and also not clearly understanding how to properly clear CSS rules within a media query.

Is there anything obvious I've done wrong that I could fix to help resolve the issue? It's hard to see the effect in the tiny result window, so if there's a way to make it full-screen in the browser, hopefully you can see what I'm talking about.

```css
.lightbox {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lightbox-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  max-height: 720px;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  margin-left: -50%;
}

.responsive-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.responsive-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1299px) {
  .lightbox {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .lightbox-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .responsive-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  }
  .responsive-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myLightbox" class="lightbox">
  <div class="lightbox-content">
    <div class="responsive-container">
      <iframe class="responsive-iframe" id="lightbox-window" name="lightbox-window" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/261201719" frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```